# How can I theme individual fields in a row?

Tags: views, theming, 8

I'm having trouble doing something that I think should be relatively simple Drupal 8 views.

I have a content type called Countries. I would like to display the 3 latest country nodes on my homepage in a views block. Each country is displayed with the class "views-row" on the container div. I am using `views--view--unformatted--countries--block_1.html.twig` to theme the output.

I would like to output something like the following markup:

```
<a class="view-row-1" href="/link/to/node">
    <img src="source-of-teaser-image.png">
    <h3>Title of node</h3>
</a>

<a class="view-row-2" href="/link/to/node">
    <img src="source-of-teaser-image.png">
    <h3>Title of node</h3>
</a>

<a class="view-row-3" href="/link/to/node">
    <img src="source-of-teaser-image.png">
    <h3>Title of node</h3>
</a>
```

The problem I'm having is accessing individual fields in the template.
If I use a view mode, I can access individual fields. If I select "show fields" in the view, I can add a field for "view result counter" and "path", which would allow me to add the "view-row-N" class and link the a tag to the node, but I can't get access to the fields individually. I have the `{{ row.content }}` variable, but any attempt to dig further into the variable (eg row.content.field_name) gives me nothing and calling a `{{ dump(row.content) }}` crashes the website.

I can't output this as a view mode for 2 reasons. I don't have access to the "view result counter" or "path" fields in a view mode and, even if I had these variables, some fields would be nested inside others (The image and title are nested inside the )

I feel this should really be as simple as

```
<a class="view-row-{{ row.content.view_result_counter }}" href="{{ row.content.path }}">
```

etc but I've tried everything I can think of. Am I completely on the wrong path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the wrong track. If you want to rewrite in twig how the fields are built to a row, you have to use the template `views-view-fields.html.twig`.

But the simplest method would be to rewrite the result of the fields in views ui. This is the option *"Override the output of this field with custom text"*. If you apply this on the last field and hide all previous fields with the option *"Exclude from display"*, you can see the twig variables for all fields in *"Replacement patterns"* and you are able to rewrite the complete row like the example you have shown in the question.