# If logic in a view template overwrite

Tags: views, 8, theming

I have a view that has several decimal fields. I want to output the fields based on their value.

Can I use a view template overwrite and twig if statement for that? Specifically

1. Output the field value in a variable.
2. Check the value of field
3. Based on value add different span around the field output.

Is template overwrite the best approach or maybe I should use a hook?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend neither template nor hook. Rewrite the fields in UI, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218022/drupal-8-views-theming-question

Comment: @4k4 And where do I include the if logic? Can't see that on the question you linked.

Comment: You can use {% if ... %}

Comment: @4k4 Thanks for the input. Works as it should but because the fields have many occurrences a more global approach would be better.

Comment: OK, this would be a custom views field plugin, you can generate one with Drupal Console.