# How to render views link field in twig?

Tags: views, theming

I have created a view that has many fields including a link field.
I am using a twig template. my view twig name is `views-view-fields--dashboard--block_3.html.twig` It works nicely but I need to render a path in an anchor tag. here is my code.

```
<a href="{{ fields.view_node.content}}">
    <div class="mail-contnet">
        <h5>{{ fields.title.content }}</h5>
        <span class="mail-desc">{{ fields.body.content }}</span>
        <span class="time">{{ fields.created.content }}</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

In the anchor tag, I am getting the link but it has twig debugging wrappers. The result is bellow

```
<a href="    
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_view_field' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/modules/views/templates/views-view-field.html.twig' -->
/vanss/ques-curabitur-arcu-erat-accumsan-id-imperdiet-et-0
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/modules/views/templates/views-view-field.html.twig' -->    
">
```

and I need only the path. I have already tried the **twig_field_value** module. but when I `{{ fields.view_node.content|field_value}}`

> Error: Cannot use object of type Drupal\Core\Render\Markup as array in
>   Drupal\twig_field_value\Twig\Extension\FieldValueExtension->isFieldRenderArray()
>   (line 171 of
>   modules\contrib\twig_field_value\src\Twig\Extension\FieldValueExtension.php).

Now I am looking for how to render the value of an anchor tag without any wrapper.

Comment: I think you have enabled  Twig Debugging in services.yml file ,just make debug = false

Comment: Better put the Twig code in the rewrite section of the field in UI, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218022/drupal-8-views-theming-question

Comment: @4k4 I have to use some inline CSS and some conditions which I can't get through rewrite fields

Comment: But for that part you have shown in the question you can rewrite the field. For other things you can still use the views templates or other methods like a custom field handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove twig debug comments you can use [striptags filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/striptags.html)

Like the following:

```
{{ fields.view_node.content|striptags}}
```

Comment: Working Like a Charm. Thanks

Comment: Welcome I'm glad that help