# How do I alter a view and add/change the form action in Entity View Attachment (eva) with table format?

Tags: 8, views

I have 2 related content types (*Order* and *Proposals*). In the *Order Detail* page, I attach the proposals for that order using EVA with table format.

> [image: screenshot]

I want to add an action button (vote) in EVA output (orange colored box buttons), so that when it's clicked, it updates the *Vote* field in the corresponding proposal node. I don't know where to start.

I've tried using `hook_view_pre_render()` but I can't find the corresponding object because the `dpm()` breaks the site.

This is the code I am using.

```php
function mymodule_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == 'order_proposal_list') {
    $results = $view->result;
    dpm($view); // This breaks the site.
    ddm($view); // This outputs 300000 and more lines in drupal_debug.txt.
  }
}
```

Somehow, I can get that field value using this code, but it's still not enough.

```php
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables)  {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  if ($view->id() == 'order_quotation_list') {
    if ($variables['field']->field == 'edit_node') {
      dpm($variables['output']);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's too late to change field plugins at this stage. You have to configure them in the View.

You could create a custom field handler plugin providing the button link and make it available in Views via [hook_views_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/).

On a higher level of the Entity API entities define operations. You can add your own in [hook_entity_operation()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_operation) or alter them in the corresponding alter hook. To use them in a View add the field *Operation Links*. The existing core operations edit/delete are only displayed for users who have access.

On a lower level, directly adding the HTML markup of the button to the field, use the rewrite input box of the Views field UI. See [How can I theme individual fields in a row?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218022/how-can-i-theme-individual-fields-in-a-row)