# How to show a field in a view for another field?

Tags: theming, 9

I have twig template named `views-view-field--banner--block_1--field-banner.html.twig` Here I print
`<a href="">{{ output -}}</a>`
To put an anchor tag around an image field named field_banner. I also have another field named `field_slider_banner_link` that I want to print within the `href=""`. But I have no clue how to get the value from that other field into this template.

Answer (score 1):

If the template provides a `row` variable (check the available variables in the Twig comments) and is not a [table](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278890/how-to-access-raw-data-in-twig-template-using-views-table-format):

*views-view-field.html.twig:*

```
{{ view.field.other_field.getvalue(row) }}
```

See also [How can I theme individual fields in a row?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218022/how-can-i-theme-individual-fields-in-a-row)

Comment: Thanks it works! But it's printing a `#` behind the value for some reason. Do you know why?

Comment: Don't know, but theming Views fields in templates is not always the best idea. Views is in the first place a UI tool. Did you try the linked topic? Seems to be about your use case.

Comment: Yeah I tried, that doesn't work for me. Also I twig's dump() doesn't work, altough I enabled twig debugging etc.